# Merge columns and assign it to a column in pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 2 pandas dataframes in the below formats:

```
df1:

Code     Temp    tmp_Code   tmp_Age
ABCDFG   NaN     ABCDF      NaN
ABCDEF   15      ABCDE      NaN

df2

Code   Temp
ABCDF  18
ABCDL  21
```

I am trying to merge 2 pandas dataframes based on tmp_Code in df1 with Code in df2. If there is a match, value in df2['Temp'] has to be filled in df1['tmp_Age']. I was able to do the join but not sure how to assign it to df1['tmp_Age'].

Code I tried:

```
df['tmp_Age'] = pd.merge(df[['tmp_Code','Temp']], df2[['Code','Temp']],left_on='tmp_Code',right_on='Code',how='left')
```

Desired output:

```
Code     Temp    tmp_Code   tmp_Age
ABCDFG   NaN     ABCDF      18
ABCDEF   15      ABCDE      NaN
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column `Temp_y` and set it as a new column:

```
df['tmp_Age'] = pd.merge(df[['tmp_Code','Temp']], df2[['Code','Temp']],
                         left_on='tmp_Code', right_on='Code',
                         how='left')['Temp_y']  # <- HERE
print(df)

# Output:
     Code  Temp tmp_Code  tmp_Age
0  ABCDFG   NaN    ABCDF     18.0
1  ABCDEF  15.0    ABCDE      NaN
```

Alternative to merge one column from a dataframe to another:

```
df['tmp_Age'] = df['tmp_Code'].map(df2.set_index('Code')['Temp'])
print(df)

# Output:
     Code  Temp tmp_Code  tmp_Age
0  ABCDFG   NaN    ABCDF     18.0
1  ABCDEF  15.0    ABCDE      NaN
```

Comment: @user3447653. Does it solve your problem?